# Sequelize: can you use hooks to add a comment to a query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

[Heroku recently posted a list of some good tips for postgres](https://blog.heroku.com/postgres-essentials#track-the-source-of-your-queries). I was most intreged by the *Track the Source of Your Queries* section. I was curious if this was something that's possible to use with Sequelize. [I know that sequelize has hooks](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/hooks/), but wasn't sure if hooks could be used to make actual query string adjustments.

I'm curious if it's possible to use a hook or another Sequelize method to append a comment to Sequelize query (without using `.raw`) to keep track of where the query was called from.

(Appending and prepending to queries would also be [helpful for implementing row-level security](http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/auditing-users-and-roles-in-postgresql/), specifically `set role` / `reset role`)

Edit: Would it be possible to use `sequelize.fn()` for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to just insert a "tag" into the SQL query you could use [`Sequelize.literal()`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#literalval-sequelizeliteral) to pass a literal string to the query generator. Adding this to `options.attributes.include` will add it, however it will also need an alias so you would have to pass some kind of value as well.

```js
 Model.findById(id, {
   attributes: {
     include: [
       [Sequelize.literal('/* your comment */ 1'), 'an_alias'],
     ],
   },
 });
```

This would produce SQL along the lines of

```sql
SELECT `model`.`id`, /* your comment */ 1 as `an_alias`
FROM `model` as `model`
WHERE `model`.`id` = ???
```

I played around with automating this a bit and it probably goes beyond the scope of this answer, but you could modify the `Sequelize.Model.prototype` before you create a connection using `new Sequelize()` to tweak the handling of the methods. You would need to do this for all the methods you want to "tag".

```js
 // alias findById() so we can call it once we fiddle with the input
 Sequelize.Model.prototype.findById_untagged = Sequelize.Model.prototype.findById;

 // override the findbyId() method so we can intercept the options.
 Sequelize.Model.prototype.findById = function findById(id, options) {
   // get the caller somehow (I was having trouble accessing the call stack properly)
   const caller = ???;

   // you need to make sure it's defined and you aren't overriding settings, etc
   options.attributes.include.push([Sequelize.literal('/* your comment */ 1'), 'an_alias']);

   // pass it off to the aliased method to continue as normal
   return this.findById_untagged(id, options);
 }

 // create the connection
 const connection = new Sequelize(...);
```

**Note**: it may not be possible to do this automagically as Sequelize has `use strict` so the `arguments.caller` and `arguments.callee` properties are not accessible.

**2nd Note**: if you don't care about modifying the `Sequelize.Model` prototypes you can also abstract your calls to the Sequelize methods and tweak the options there.

```
function Wrapper(model) {
  return {
    findById(id, options) {
      // do your stuff
      return model.findById(id, options);
    },
  };
}

Wrapper(Model).findById(id, options);
```

**3rd Note**: You can also submit a pull request to add this functionality to [Sequelize](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize) under a new option value, like `options.comment`, which is added at the end of the query.

Comment: thank you for a thorough and well thought-out answer. I am very impressed. Maybe for caller some hack like `try { throw new Error(); } catch ( error ) { console.log( error.stack ); }` could work if it choose the correct line from the stack, but would be slow ;)

Answer (score 0):

This overrides the `sequelize.query()` method that's internally used by Sequelize for all queries to add a comment showing the location of the query in the code. It also adds the stack trace to errors thrown.

```
const excludeLineTexts = ['node_modules', 'internal/process', ' anonymous ', 'runMicrotasks', 'Promise.'];

// overwrite the query() method that Sequelize uses internally for all queries so the error shows where in the code the query is from
sequelize.query = function () {
    let stack;
    const getStack = () => {
        if (!stack) {
            const o = {};
            Error.captureStackTrace(o, sequelize.query);
            stack = o.stack;
        }
        return stack;
    };

    const lines = getStack().split(/\n/g).slice(1);
    const line = lines.find((l) => !excludeLineTexts.some((t) => l.includes(t)));

    if (line) {
        const methodAndPath = line.replace(/(\s+at (async )?|[^a-z0-9.:/\\\-_ ]|:\d+\)?$)/gi, '');

        if (methodAndPath) {
            const comment = `/* ${methodAndPath} */`;
            if (arguments[0]?.query) {
                arguments[0].query = `${comment} ${arguments[0].query}`;
            } else {
                arguments[0] = `${comment} ${arguments[0]}`;
            }
        }
    }

    return Sequelize.prototype.query.apply(this, arguments).catch((err) => {
        err.fullStack = getStack();
        throw err;
    });
};
```